# How to increase Timeout in stored procedure of SQL Azure

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have one stored procedure in SQl Azure is calling periodically at 5 minutes and processing crore of data and it sometimes give Timeout error as per below as per my log.

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of
>   the operation or the server is not responding.

**How can i increase Timeout of this query or whole Db? and what would be default Timeout?**

**Update**

I think Time out is not due to connection to sql azure here as per answers of @Ming and @Ruchit because when i have checked the log then below error it will display message like

> Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET
>   operation.

It means query is being executed, above message because of i have used some aggregate function on NULL value. Am i thinking correct? what should be other possible cause?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ssdsgetstarted/thread/7070c2f9-07d1-4935-82c2-b74a196908ee/, SQL Azure will close idle connections that are longer than 5 minutes. As you mentioned you’re calling the stored procedure every 5 minutes, thus you may be on the edge of timeout. I would like to suggest you to change to every 4 minutes to see whether it works.

In addition, when using SQL Azure, retry is very important. When a query fails, please close the connection, wait for a few seconds, and then create a new connection, try the query again. Usually the second time will work fine.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Answer (score 1):

Ming Xu is right. the cause of the error is most probably the 5 minute timeout. 
If you can not change the time period to call the stored procedure, one option is to make dummy call to SQL Azure every 3 or 4 mins. This will keep the connection from being closed.